# Magento2.3: The attribute 'data-requiremodule' is not allowed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, upgrade, requirejs

I upgraded the Magento version 2.1 to **2.3**, the following error has occurred in the backend.

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'script', attribute 'data-requiremodule': The attribute 'data-requiremodule' is not allowed. Line: 186
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the attribute `data-requiremodule` is not valid for Magento 2.3 any more. I'm assuming one of your xml files still has a script added like this

`<script src="Vendor_Module::/js/example.js" data-requiremodule="anotherscript" />`

Which is causing the error to occur.

In order to find the offending xml you can do a grep search in CLI

e.g.

`grep -ril 'script.*data-requiremodule' <Magento_Docroot>`

This should provide a list of files which contain this offending declaration.

You can then change the declaration and should fix your immediate issue.

Next you will have to see what that javascript does and maybe change it to use `require` properly

e.g.

```
require(['anotherscript'], function($){
  //code here
});
```

You can read more about available attributes in 2.3 at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html#layout-types-conf